# wp_mail file attachment not being placed in upload folder?

Tags: php, attachments, forms, wp-mail

I have a form where I want users to be able to select an image to upload. The image gets temporarily uploaded to the wp-content/uploads folder, is attached to the e-mail and then is destroyed.

Right now, the form is submitting and I can see that the image is being processed in the response headers, but there is no image included in the e-mail and there is no image file in the uploads folder. Does anyone see any issues with this code?

Here's the form:

```
<form id="shareForm" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/file-form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" class="upload">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And here's my PHP mail script:

```
<?php
    require( '../../../../wp-load.php' );

if(isset($_POST["name"])){

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $fName = str_replace(array(' ', ',', '\'' ), '-');

    $date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
    $myDate = $date->format("m/d/Y H:i");
    $fileDate = $date->format("m-d-Y");
    $homeUrl = home_url('/');

    if($_FILES["file"]["type"] != ""){

        $allowedExts = array("jpg", "png", "gif");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
        $newFileName = $fName . $fileDate."." .$extension;

        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            $myPath =  $homeUrl . 'share/?upload=error';
            wp_redirect($myPath); exit;     

        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/uploads/user-submitted/" . $newFileName);
        }

    }

    $to = 'my@email.com';
    $subject = $fName . " submitted a photo";

    $message = "Date: " . $myDate . " EST \n";
    $message .= "Message:  " .$message. "\n";

    $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/uploads/user-submitted/".$newFileName); 
    $headers[] = 'From: Photo Submissions <my@email.com>';

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);

    unlink(WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/uploads/user-submitted/" . $newFileName);

    $myPath =  $homeUrl . 'share/?upload=success';
    wp_redirect($myPath); 
    exit;   

}

?>
```

Comment: You should really consider looking at `wp_mail()`. Just search the site to see some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachments should always use the absolute filesystem path.

Also to change the `Content-Type` of the email you should use the `wp_mail_content_type` filter.

```
<?php
function my_custom_email() {
    $to  = 'my@email.com';
    $subject = 'WordPress wp_mail';
    $message = '
    <html>
    <body>
        <table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">
          <tr>Hello WordPress</tr>
        </table>          
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    $attachments = array(  WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/my-plugin/uploads/sample_photo_01.jpg' );
    $headers[] = 'From: '.get_option( 'blogname' ).' <'.get_option( 'admin_email' ).'>';
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'my_custom_email_content_type' );
    return wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
}

function my_custom_email_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
```

I have placed the entire code in a function so that the wp_mail_content_type filter applies only to this email.

Sources:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type

OR
You can try this code

```
 $attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip' );
   $headers = 'From: My Name <myname@example.com>' . "\r\n";
   wp_mail('test@example.org', 'subject', 'message', $headers, $attachments );
```